# IdentityServer4, signing credentials

Tags: identityserver4, credentials

IdentityServer's `AddSigningCredentials` extension method requires a certificate or an instance of the `SigningCredentials` class. Everything is nice and easy if this certificate has a CSP. But the CNG certificates cause an exception `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified`, since CNG certificates have their own way to obtain their private keys.

So we have to use the `SigningCredentials` class, but it's confusing. We have to generate our own `AsymmetricSecurityKeys` somehow based on a persistant string or there are other ways?

What is correct way to solve our situation? Several hours of googling haven't clarified this case, so it will be great, if an example is provided.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If so, could you answer and show how? I'm in the same boat right now.

Comment: No we have not. Fortunatelly our customers still use the legacy certificates